# My animals disappeared, kinda

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-spigot

My cows, sheep, and llama disappeared! [image: animals gone]

Except... they didn't. I can still hear them mooing and baaing and... whatever llamas do. I can't hit them with my sword (nothing happens, it's like they're not there), but bows can hit them (and they drop loot as normal). Anyone know what's going on or how to fix it? I'm on a Spigot server running Minecraft Java 1.14.4 on a MacBook.

(Also, I can't see illagers, but pillagers can see and shoot me.)

Comment: Have you tried reconnecting?

Comment: Yeah, multiple times

Comment: Could you ask him to restart the server? Could be a bug that is easily fixed by stopping and starting the server again.

Comment: I've had this happen before on the PS3 edition. I just walked to another chunk and came back and they were there.

Comment: Llamas hack and spit. Me and my family used to have some Alpacas that spitted on everything. Including us. :)

Comment: According to the subtitles, llamas "bleat":

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the server simply needed a restart. The admin restarted the server and all was good.

Comment: It would still be interesting to know what caused this, so if you ever have this happen enough that you know how to reproduce this, you should create a bug report (if there isn't one already).

Answer (score -3):

Tell the server adimin/creater of the server or try loging in and out

Comment: I have done both of those things, server admin didn't know what's going on (it's not just my client, they've disappeared for him too) and logging out/in doesn't do anything.

Comment: I know this might be a relevant answer I would just wait till tomorrow

Comment: The issue started happening yesterday and hasn't fixed itself yet.

Comment: Oh my bad maybe restart your pc laptop and your router

Comment: You no what that was a dumb thing to say  you probably already did that